# A Parliament with many Houses with restricted competence

Tags: democracy, political-theory

Please forgive the naivety of my question (and adjust the tags if necessary, I'm a newbie).

Often, election campaigns are dominated by one or two themes. Populist parties profit from this. One remedy could be to have many Houses (say, 10 or more) each with a restricted domain of competence.

Has this ever been seriously studied? I would really appreciate some references.

Comment: I asked a [similar question](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11670/effective-differences-between-legislatures-by-number-of-houses), which had a decent answer.  You may find it relevant.

Comment: Then you would just have infighting between the houses regarding who is responsible for what.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, and I'd love to see an answer with references, but I think @Philipp is right about the practicality.  Is a law restricting what jobs foreign workers can take an economic law?  A foreign policy law? An immigration law?  Who would have responsibility for it?  ----- That said, the US's collection of regulatory agencies (FCC, FTC, FAA, etc) could be a good parallel.  They each have their own areas, but things that overlap are affected by both.

Answer (score 6):

> One remedy could be to have many Houses (say, 10 or more) each with a restricted domain of competence.

But those kinds of restrictions tend not to work in practice.  For example in the United States (US), all tax bills are supposed to originate in the House.  But the Senate gets around this by taking an existing bill with any kind of tax whatsoever and replacing it in its entirety with their own bill.  [Example](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/2402/4666) of a tax bill that effectively started in the US Senate.

How do you divide competencies?  For example, you could have a business legislature and an environmental legislature.  But what happens when the environmental legislature wants to regulate business practices?  Maybe they have to agree.  What happens if you add a labor legislature?  What happens if it is a military contractor?  Does the defense legislature also get involved?  Foreign Affairs might get involved with an international company.

Who chooses the legislatures?  Do I have to vote for ten or more representatives, each with specialized competencies that I don't really understand?  What happens if I just vote for less spending and taxes?

To some extent this is already done.  Each legislature tends to have specialized committees with a subset of the overall legislators.  The overall legislature still votes on the final bills, but the details are mostly set in the committee.  [US House committees.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_House_of_Representatives_committees)

Comment: Thank you, I expected such an answer. Suppose, an external (non elected) organ decides which chambers are competent. It may be more than one. Then  compromises will be made between chambers and *not* between political parties.